# aframe embeded scene with cursor mouse ray-origin

Tags: javascript, aframe

There seems to be a bug with the embedded scene and the option of mouse cursor (cursor='rayOrigin: mouse'),
i've put an mouseenter and mouseleave event on a box to change it's size. It works fine as long as the page is contained in the browser, but when the page is "scrollable" the events get messed up ( like showed in the gif, link bellow). I don't know if I messed up somewhere but it seems that it comes from Aframe. There's a link bellow for the github issue ( more details on it).

GIF : 
[image: screenshot]

Github Issue :
https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3410

Comment: What exactly is the question you want to ask / the thing you want to know? You should follow the StackOverflow Q/A format. However, I can not find any question here. May you please add a specific question?

Comment: Sorry i guess this more a of bug than a question, my question would be how resolve this bug but that may be too vague. I just wanted to see if someone else had the same problem.

Comment: If it is inappropriate for stackoverflow i'll just take it off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mouse-cursor` component uses the whole window to calculate the position, so You'd have to rewrite it, to utilize the `<canvas>` for raycasting.

There is a workaround, you can make a fullscreen scene and put it in an `<i-frame>`, where the `window` is the iframe's body.

Example [here](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/silent-lamb?path=index.html:4:59).

Comment: i'm not sure understand how it works (never used i-frame), would you mind just showing an example (link or fiddle if possible :p)? Anyway thanks for the response. And btw do you think Aframe devs will take a look into it ?

Comment: @tiagoERNST updated, i've added an example, i'm not sure if they want to change it since it's dedicated for VR, not PC's

Comment: Thank you ! And yeah i can understand they won't be that much interested in it.

Comment: if you don't have further questions feel free to mark the anwser :)